# GoogleMap with header div extends beyond window size

Tags: css, reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

Note: I've seen some similar questions and tried their answers (CSS position: absolute), but they are all ~7 years old and did not solve my problem.

I am making a simple React app with an interactive Google Map with a header that displays information from the map. However, the map always expands a bit below the page, causing the page to scroll up/down by the same amount as the header size.

[This is a demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/gmaps-header-css-test-1j2ld?file=/src/App.js), which does what is described above, along with relevant code snippets:

HTML (served via React component, as seen in demo)

```
<div>
  <div className="row-header">
  </div>

  <div className="mapContainer">
    <GoogleMap id="map" mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle} zoom={4} />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row-header {
  min-height: 305px;
  display: flex;
}

.col-left {
  width: 33%;
}

.col-right {
  width: 66%;
}

.mapContainer {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

After some research, I found that I should try **CSS absolute positioning**, however this has not helped. [This is a demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/gmaps-header-css-absolute-test-762j0?file=/src/styles.css:251-433) of that new version:

HTML

```
<div>
  <div className="row-header">
  </div>

  <div className="mapContainer">
    <GoogleMap id="map" mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle} zoom={4} />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row-header {
  min-height: 305px;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 305px;
}

.mapContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 305px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.Container {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was writing this question discovered the answer. Figured I might as well post and share.

The CSS Absolute Position fix DOES WORK, however in this particular case the fix is not done in the CSS, but in the Javascript. That is because [@react-google-maps/api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/api),  uses `mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle}`, which seems to be a required field (although [the docs](http://%3CGoogleMap%20id=%22map%22%20mapContainerStyle=%7BmapContainerStyle%7D%20zoom=%7B4%7D%20/%3E) don't make that clear).

After modying mapContainerStyle
from

```
const mapContainerStyle = {
  height: "100vh",
  width: "100vw"
};
```

to

```
const mapContainerStyle = {
  position: "absolute",
  top: "305px",
  left: "0px",
  right: "0px",
  bottom: "0px"
};
```

The page displays as intended! [See Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/gmaps-header-css-absolute-test-2dxzb?file=/src/styles.css)

Comment: You could: 1) set HTML `<body>` margins to `0` or another value so you control it and 2) simply set the map container height with [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) (100vh *minus* header height *minus* body top/bottom margins) so if body margin is `0`: `height: calc(100vh - 305px)` - no need for absolute positioning.